# drawText and hardware acceleration

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm using drawText to write a description on my marker in my map fragment. I read several post and Android documentation. My app supports API 11 and above. I don't well understand the Android doc about the use of drawText and hw acceleration. I used the emulator ICS but I don't if it's a good proof and my phone is 4.3 and Android docs talks about canvas scaling problem on API < 18. So my question, is it necessary to turn off the hw acceleration in API < 18 in order to correctly use canvas drawText?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found :) If you use your own canvas object isHardwareAccelerated returns always false. The problems with hw acceleration can happen only with canvas onDraw parameter of your own view (if hw acceleration is enabled), so in my case I work always in sw.